# JS problema al añadir un símbolo delante del @ en campo de correo

Tags: javascript, email, textfield

tengo el siguiente código:

```
mail = new Ext.form.TextField({
           hideLabel:true,
           id: 'mail',
           name: 'mail1',
           style:'margin-top:2px;',
           widht:200});

var fila = new Ext.Panel({
          layout: 'table',
          layoutConfig: {columns: 4},
          items:({
      new Ext.form.Label({
                   text: 'correo elec. :',
                   style:'margin-right:10px;font-family:tahoma,arial,helvetica',
                   width:100}),
                   mail,
.....................................................................
```

El campo mail funciona, si añado símbolos como "-", "/" sigue funcionando, el problema es cuando los inserto justo delante del "@" ¿Qué se podría hacer? Gracias.

Comment: No comentas mucho sobre el contexto. El problema es ese, pero... ¿estás utilizando alguna librería en general? ¿Utilizas alguna herramienta de validación? Me imagino (más bien intuyo) que el problema viene por ahí, pero es difícil si no vemos/conocemos el contexto

Comment: Cierto la validación, encontré que está insertada para el DNI, pero no encontré la del correo, por lo que se me olvidó totalmente, fallo mío. A ver si consigo averiguar donde está ¡Gracias!